# How to order input arguments for a generated function

Tags: matlab, input, arguments, output

How do I change The order of input arguments? For `fncA_approx()`, the input arguments are ordered (`height, t`) which is actually counter intuitive. How do I control input argument orders of the output of `matlabFunction` so the input arguments are arranged (`t, height`)?

```
%% 1.10 Torricelli's equation_; %'//


syms Qua t Area height alf

% (a)
%delta_Height = dsolve('Dheight = (3*Qua*((sin(t))^2) - (alf*( 1+ height)^1.5))/Area', 'height(0) = 0')
% (b)
dHeight_dt = (3*Qua*(sin(t))^2 - alf*( 1+ height)^1.5)/Area
fnca_approx = subs(dHeight_dt, {Area, Qua, alf}, {1250, 450, 150})
fncA_approx = matlabFunction(fnca_approx)
%%
step = 0.5;
t = 0:step:10; 
height = ones(size(t)); 
k = 1; 
height(1) = 0; 
 while k < length(t)
 height(k + 1) = height(k) + step*fncA_approx(height(k),t(k)); 
 k = k+1; 
 end; 
height'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/matlabfunction.html)

> Use the `Vars` argument to specify the order of input arguments for the generated MATLAB function.

```
syms x y z t
r = (x + y/2 + z/3)*exp(-t);
matlabFunction(r,'Vars',{t,x,z,y})

ans = 
    @(t,x,z,y)exp(-t).*(x+y.*(1.0./2.0)+z.*(1.0./3.0))
```